# Write jBehave example step

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jbehave

I want to write a jBehave step as follows;

```
@When("I perform <someAction> on $panel")
```

So I can have steps like

```
i. When I perform Action1 on Panel1
ii. When I perform Action2 on Panel2
```

Now as you can see, this step has a mix of placeholder

```
1. someAction which actually comes via meta
2. $panel which is taken from the step text in the story
```

But this is not working from me and I get NullPointerException

It works if I write

```
@When("I perform <someAction> on Panel1")
```

i.e. I cannot use the 2 placeholders in the same step.

But since this is a generic step, I do not want to hard code any values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

```
@When("I perform <someAction> on *panel*")
public void perform(@Named("panel") String panelId){

}
```

and from now, I recommend to identify all elements by name, using jemmy you can use a `new NameComponentChooser(panelId)`

Comment: Actually I need 2 parameters for the method; panelId and someAction

Comment: there is no a limit on @Named parameters, check http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/parameter-injection.html

Answer (score 0):

Please use $symbol before both your parameters. Then both the example parameter as well as the normal parameter will be handled.

```
@When("I perform $action on $panel")
public void performAction(String action, String panel){
}
```